# Javascript - how to reset fields onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry. Javascript (using jquery) noob here. Here is the question.

I have a select field with numbers:

```
<div class="controls">
  <select class="span2" id='select1' onchange="addstuff()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="addfields"></div>
```

I then loop through the number specified, and add some html within the div tag that has the
id of "select1".

```
function addstuff()
{
  var num = parseInt($('#select1').val())
  if (num != 0)
  {
    for (i=0; i<num;i++)
      {
        new_field += "<p>" + num + "</p>";
      }
  $('#addfields').html(new_field);
  }
}
```

So if I select the option of 3, the following html will be added:

```
<p> + num + </p>
<p> + num + </p>
<p> + num + </p>
```

However, if I select 2, 2 more fields will be appended:

```
<p> + num + </p>
<p> + num + </p>
<p> + num + </p>
<p> + num + </p>
<p> + num + </p>
```

However, I want the previous html to be scrubbed, and I only want two entries.

```
<p> + num + </p>
<p> + num + </p>
```

If someone could please help me see what I am missing, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy peasy, thanks for adding that much explanation and code... this should do what you want:

```
function addstuff()
{
  var num = parseInt($('#select1').val());
  var new_field = "";
  if (num != 0)
  {
    for (i=0; i<num;i++)
      {
        new_field += "<p>" + num + "</p>";
      }
  $('#addfields').html(new_field);
  }
}
```

mainly it looks like you are  not re-initializing that new_field variable so its just building up... because the jquery .html() will overwrite whatever is in that addfields, meaning if you are seeing build up it is because your new_field variable actually contains the build up.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `new_field`, which you should do anyway.  If you do, your problem will be fixed too.

```
function addstuff() {
    var new_field = '';
```

---

By the way since you are using jQuery it's even easier to use event bindings than event attributes.  Instead of `onchange="addstuff()"`, do:

```
$("#select1").on('change', addstuff);
```

You could also forego defining `addstuff` and bind it as an anonymous function.

Comment: For sure. I wanted to upvote here, but my reputation isn't high enough. Your solution seems really clean wrt event bindings. Going to read up on this, and I will most likely rewrite my code. Thank you again.